# memory error in matrix cosine_similarity

Tags: scikit-learn, recommender-system, cosine-distance, movielens

I have (20905040, 7)
of a dataset to recommend 10 different product to the user
it could be larger than that but anyway I got memory error when processing the

```
cosine_sim = cosine_similarity(normalized_df,normalized_df)
```

> --------------------------------------------------------------------------- MemoryError                               Traceback (most recent call
>   last)  in 
>         1 get_ipython().run_line_magic('time', '')
>   ----> 2 cosine_sim = cosine_similarity(normalized_df,normalized_df)
>
> ~/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/metrics/pairwise.py in
>   cosine_similarity(X, Y, dense_output)    1034     1035     K =
>   safe_sparse_dot(X_normalized, Y_normalized.T,
>   -> 1036                         dense_output=dense_output)    1037     1038     return K
>
> ~/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/utils/extmath.py in
>   safe_sparse_dot(a, b, dense_output)
>       140         return ret
>       141     else:
>   --> 142         return np.dot(a, b)
>       143 
>       144
>
> MemoryError:

questions 
1. when I have too much rows how do I apply cosine similarity?
2. do they talking about ram memory? or what memory error ? 
3. is there way to use gpu for cosine similarity training?
4. any good idea?

Comment: You'd really have to specify what's in this data set? 20.9M users and you are dotting them with themselves? that's about 218 _trillion_ similarities to compute. That will never work. You usually dot a user vector with item vectors after obtaining them from say ALS.

Answer (score 2):

This is talking about RAM. There are a few factors that will decide how many rows/columns you can use. Instead of rows/columns, it is maybe easier to just think in total number of elements: `num_rows * num_cols`. The memory you will require is going to have a relationship to this number.

There are ways that might take less working memory to solve the problem - usually memory and speed are part of the trade-off. If you use a lot less memory while computing the result, you can do fewer at a time and so it takes longer.

If you have floating point numbers (those with decimals), then Pandas usually uses the data type `float64` by default. You could try using `float32` instead. It offers about half of the accuracy, but also only uses half of the memory. You can do this by simply adding this line before you compute the `cosine_similarity`:

```
import numpy as np

normalized_df = normalized_df.astype(np.float32)
cosine_sim = cosine_similarity(normalized_df, normalized_df)
```

Here is [a thread about using Keras to compute cosine similarity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51003027/computing-cosine-similarity-between-two-tensors-in-keras), which can then be done on the GPU. I would point out, that (single) GPUs will generally have less working memory available than your computer itself.

Here is [a blog that speaks about how to scale up your computation](https://medium.com/@rantav/large-scale-matrix-multiplication-with-pyspark-or-how-to-match-two-large-datasets-of-company-1be4b1b2871e) to use tools like Spark, for distributed computing. That would allow you to deal with much larger matrices, provided you have several computers available.